# How to debug in nightwatch

Tags: debugging, nightwatch.js

I am trying to debug in nightwatch.
When I put in a console.log it prints before the test runs - while its doing some sort of construction/compiling of the test.
I tried also visual studio code debugger and same thing - the breakpoint hits before the tests are actually run.
thanks for help - mark

Comment: What error are you getting? The question, as posed, lacks specificity. What file are you modifying to add your console statement?

Answer (score 14):

"nightwatch" is built on node.js. Node.js executes statements asynchronously. If you write `console.log();`, it will be executed asynchronously.

The statements you write using `browser` (or `client`) object (e.g. `browser.url();` , `browser.click();` etc.) will be queued up at Selenium Server. They are also executed asynchronously by node.js but are queued up at selenium server.

To perform `console.log()` in sync with other statements in nightwatch, use [`.perform()`](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#perform). You will get output in sync with other statements.

### Example

```js
var elementValue;
browser
.getValue('.some-element', function(result) {
  elementValue = result.value;
})
// other stuff going on ...
//
// self-completing callback
.perform(function() {
  console.log('elementValue', elementValue);
  // without any defined parameters, perform
  // completes immediately (synchronously)
})
.end();
```

For debugging purpose, you can stop the execution to find out element values or check the browser related data. Use this command: [`browser.pause();`](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#pause) (or `client.pause();`). Do not pass any timer here. It will stop the execution.

Comment: Is there any way to log to the nightwatch output console when running console.log in the browser? This would be useful in CI where its hard to debug issues?

Answer (score 0):

As you don't really have an example, or some code that you run, i can only give you the general direction you can try in order to fix the issue.

This happens because your code is ran asynchronously (cause that's how javascript works) and everything that is not browser/html related will run before your browser starts your actual test. I suggest you should try using ***callbacks*** in order avoid printing your check msgs first (this way you link the `console.log` to your code that depends on the browser and it will run only after this finishes. If you do that, the debugging with console log will actually work.

Maybe you can learn [here](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) how to do that, as an example.