# console.log does not print to the console when written in a test case in the Nightwatch using Javascript

Tags: javascript, automation, ui-automation, nightwatch.js, nightwatch

```
const arr= ['A', 'B']

module.exports = {

'testCase1'(browser){
  console.log("Hello")   //Doesn't print to the console
  },


'testCase2'(browser){
  arr.forEach(myFunction);

  function myFunction(value){
        browser
            .useXpath().click(`//span[text() = "${value}"]`)
            //rest of the code
    }
  }

}
```

I am using Nightwatch for automation.

Que 1- In testCase 1, why Hello is not printed to the console when I write in the test case?

Que 2- In testcase2, It does nothing, what can be the reason?

Comment: you are missing a `,` after your first function - should be getting a syntax error

Comment: thanks, I corrected it here.Still, the problem remains the same.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36579361/how-to-debug-in-nightwatch

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I'm still not able to print it to the console.

Comment: How do you initiate your tests? there is no reason for the console.log() not to work

Comment: npm run local -- --test tests/myPlan.js